# How to prevent to relaunch specific Activity after pressed back button?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

When I pressed the back button on `B` Activity to go back `A` Activity,
 `B` Activity is relaunched 'cause `B` Activity was launched from `intent.extra` at `onCreate` of `A` Activity.

The `intent.extra` is recreated with previous data, so it happens recursively.

My intention is to load `B` Activity from `FCM` and then back to the `A` Activity when the user pressed the back button.

I already tried to remove data of intent after `startActivity` but it didn't work.
But If I check `savedInstanceState` is `null` or not, it works but I'm not sure it's the right way or not.

Plus, the `A` Activity's `launchMode` is `singleTop` but it's not the point of this problem, I think.

Whole scenarios are the following.

1. Get the data from FCM in the background and then the data is served from the System tray.
2. Check if there is data or not at `onCreate` of `A` Activity and then if there is launch `B` Activity.
3. Pressed back button on `B` Activity but `B` Activity relaunched at `onCreate` of `A` Activity.

How to prevent the action of 3 in the scenarios?